Azure FunctionApp functions not listed when publishing
I've got an Azure Functionapp that works fine locally, but I'm having trouble publishing it to Azure.
I'm using the Python v2 programming model. My project folder looks like this:
project_folder
├── .venv
├── .vscode
├── .funcignore
├── .gitignore
├── my_code_1.py
├── my_code_2.py
├── my_code_3.py
├── function_app.py
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
└── requirements.txt

Where function_app.py contains multiple functions (both blog trigger and HTTP trigger types), and the my_code_x.py modules contain helper code and various utilities.
I run the functions locally using a basic web app (html page) which connects to my Azure account for storage and models, etc. When I run it locally it works as intended.
The problem is when I try to publish the function app.
I can create it and it seems to succeed, using the following command in the terminal:
az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location <xxx> --name <xxx> --os-type linux --resource-group <xxx> --runtime python --storage-account <xxx> --functions-version 4

Then I publish using:
func azure functionapp publish <my_project_name>

It seems to work, and pip installs all the requirements and so on, and then says:
...
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-05-13T15:38:03.688Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in <my_project_name>:

I expect it to then list the functions in the project, but it doesn't list anything. When I inspect the FunctionApp in the Azure portal, there are no functions listed under "functions".


Azure FunctionApp functions not listed when publishing

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations and I have followed my SO-Thread's answer:
Below is my function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import importlib.util as rith
import sys
from pkg_resources import run_script
import os

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    rith_script('rithfile')
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello")
def rith_script(run_script):
    spath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f'{run_script}.py')
    rs = rith.spec_from_file_location(run_script, spath)
    rm = rith.module_from_spec(rs)
    sys.modules[rs.name] = rm
    rs.loader.exec_module(rm)


rithfile.py:

print("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!!")


Deployed to Portal:
func azure functionapp publish "rithtesttt"


Here rithtesttt is the function app name which i created in portal using below command:
az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location "centralindia" --name "rithtesttt" --os-type linux --resource-group "rbojja" --runtime python --storage-account "rith54" --functions-version 4

After Deployment:

Checking if Python script executed after triggering the function:

